# PHP Session for an Array is not working?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an array which I have put into a SESSION, but for some reason when I click a button on the page, instead of the list of items showing again using the id numbers from the array stored in the session, it returns to main.php (which is what I have told it to do when it isn't set)

```
$games= $_POST['games']; 

if (!empty($games)){ 
    $_SESSION["gamelist"] = $games; 
    $list = implode(',', $games);
}else {
    header('Location:./main.php'); 
}
```

Printing the result out is the code:

```
$conn  = pg_connect("host=*** port=*** dbname=*** user=*** password=*****");    
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table WHERE Id IN ($list)";

$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);
```

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

Comment: are you starting the session ? http://us3.php.net/session_start

Comment: I am indeed starting session

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you are checking the content of $_POST['games'], which is obviously not a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are retrieving data from the session variable. I only see you set it. `$list` needs to come from your session variable if it exists, and not *just* from your $_POST variable.

```
$games= $_POST['games']; 

if (!empty($games)){ 
    $_SESSION["gamelist"] = $games; 
}else {
    header('Location:./main.php'); 
}

if ( isset( $_SESSION['gamelist'] ) ) $games = $_SESSION['gamelist'];
$list = implode(',', $games);
```

Comment: I used your code, but am now getting the following errors:

`Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...ELECT column1, colum2, ..... FROM phones WHERE Id IN () ^ in ........ on line 64

Warning: pg_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ............ on line 72`

Comment: So the `$list` is empty, either session data has not persisted or was not set